# Java 8 get a field of object when another field is minimum from a list of objects

Tags: java, java-8

I have list of objects `objList` which has two fields `age` and `id`. `age` is `long` and `id` is `String`. I want to iterate over the list and get the id of object that has minimum age in the list. I can do it with a traditional `for` loop, but I am sure there would be a compact solution in java 8.

If I do `objList.stream()` and then check map functions on that stream, I just have `mapToInt`, `mapToLong`, and `mapToDouble`. With these I get the min age, but I need id of the object that has minimum age.

Its guaranteed that the list will not be empty and will have at least one object.

Comment: What if the list is empty?

Comment: Ohh in my case its guaranteed that the list will not be empty. Will add that in the description.

Comment: Why would `age` be `long`?

Comment: @shmosel Could be the raw value of a `Date`, for example.

Comment: @shmosel yes. It will be represented as unix timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
objList.stream()
        .min(Comparator.comparingLong(MyObj::getAge))
        .orElseThrow(AssertionError::new)
        .getId()
```

Comment: The `min` function returns `Optional<T>` right? So in this case it would return `Optional<MyObj>`. The optional will be empty if the list is empty.

Comment: Or without streams: `Collections.min(objList, Comparator.comparingLong(MyObj::getAge)) .getId()`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the elements in the list are of type `MyObject`, and offer accessors `getAge()` and `getId()`, the pipeline would look like this:

```
String id = objList.stream()
  .min(Comparator.comparingLong(MyObject::getAge))
  .map(MyObject::getId)
  .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

If your assumption is invalid, and `objList` *is* empty, this will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`—but that will "never happen," right? Alternatively, you could return a [default value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) or [generate one.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-)